# CentOS 6.5 gets installed in minimal mode after the message "X startup failed, falling back to text mode."

Tags: centos, system-installation, gui, desktop

I am trying to install complete CentOS 6.5 including GUI on a x86 platform (32 GB RAM, 1 TB Secondary Memory) using a DVD but for some reason only the minimal commandline CentOS gets installed after the message **"X startup failed, falling back to text mode"**. It does not ask me my choice during installation. I have earlier successfully used the same DVD to install the complete CentOS including GUI on similar platforms.  What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could be the problem?

You actually have a Desktop choice at install time. Else: Minimal.

This will do for the missing pieces : # `yum groupinstall Desktop`

Answer (score 0):

Please refer:https://www.unixmen.com/install-centos-6-5-remotely-using-telnet/
Choose Install or upgrade an existing system option from the installation wizard and press TAB key. Now you should see the following screen. Type linux text and press enter.

Comment: I don't want to command line mode. I was the full CentOS including the desktop environment.

Comment: Sorry, you may miss x11-windows, you can reinstall x11-windows.